# CPIM designation behind name

Tags: career-development, legal, name

I'm in the process of CPIM training. I know that you attach CPIM to the end of your name once completed. I was wondering if this is only in a professional environment to show you have the certification or if it is considered a suffix on all documents.

**Does the CPIM count as a suffix for documentation purposes?**

Comment: You can add it to as many or as few documents as you'd like.  Normally it is determined by your company's culture.

Comment: That certification doesn't mean anything outside of your industry, so I wouldn't add it on general documentation, letters, emails, etc.  For that matter, I'm not even sure it means much inside an industry.  The only things I might pay attention to, and only in a professional context, are indications of having a terminal degree.

Comment: Thank you I was just concerned whether it was a requirement.

Comment: *whether it was a requirement* it might make sense to check with whomever issues the certification if you're curious about requirements for tagging your name with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As with most certification-related "suffixes" you'd only really use it where it's *directly* relevant to the context.

So if you have a formal e-mail signature on your work account where you send e-mails in your capacity as a production/inventory manager you might put it there, although it's good sense to be guided by what others in your company do for a sense of whether it is culturally appropriate. In